# How to make delay before each character is printed in a string using Ruby

Tags: ruby

Does anyone know how to create a small delay (perhaps 0.1 seconds) between the printing of each character in a string in Ruby?

I have tried some other methods (shown below); however, I'm certain that a simpler method exists as the method im using is time (and space) consuming:

```
#ugly/boring method vvv

print "h"
sleep 0.1
print "e"
sleep 0.1
print "l"
sleep 0.1
print "l"
sleep 0.1
print "o"
```

I have done some research on the topic and found a method under C and php but no one seems to have an answer for Ruby.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Sorry about the grammatical errors; its partially spellchecks fault but i really am terrible and its very early :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"hello".each_char do |c|
  sleep 0.1
  print c
end
```

Docs: [String#each_char](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-each_char)

You could also monkey-patch the string class:

```
class String
  def print_slowly
    self.each_char do |c|
      sleep 0.1
      print c
    end
  end
end

#usage
"hello".print_slowly
```

Comment: thanks for this @Lev, simple and easy to understand.

Comment: `print_slowly` should be defined as a [module function](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function) in `Kernel` (not in `String`), just like [`print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-print)

Answer (score 0):

A super simple approach would be something like this:

```
"hello".split(//).each do |c|
  sleep 0.1 
  print c
end
```

Here's a more verbose explanation:

```
string = "hello"
split_that_string = string.split(//);

for character in split_that_string
   sleep 0.1
   print character
end
```

You could also make a method for it:

```
def print_a_string_one_character_at_a_time(string)
  array_of_characters = string.split(//);
  for character in array_of_characters
    sleep 0.1
    print character
  end
end
```

and then you can pass any string to that method. Here's an example:

```
print_a_string_one_character_at_a_time("Hello, World!")
```

That will type out Hello, World! one character at a time (and return the array of characters).

Comment: Thank you @OhHendrie, this method works smoothly and is simple to understand.